# Insert horizontal line in NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

After every group item (collapsible item) in an NSOutlineView, I need a horizontal line, as a separator. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it using an NSAttributedString consisting purely of blank space and underlining it.  Inelegant, but it works.